# How to sign in on github desktop?

Tags: reactjs, github, github-for-windows, github-desktop

I have installed GitHub desktop and I have tried a lot to sign in on GitHub through browser but it is not signing in and  it shows following issue.

"That address is either invalid, not a verified primary email or is not associated with a personal user account. Organization billing emails are only for notifications

I tried forget password and other things but none of them worked for me and I was expecting that it will sign in on GitHub".